# ImportError: cannot import name 'deserialize_keras_object' from partially initialized module

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, mobilenet, roboflow

I am having problems trying to run Mobilenet SSD, I take code from https://github.com/codeperfectplus/ASL.
I change the link of Roboflow dataset to mine and the required file then this error shows.

ImportError: cannot import name 'deserialize_keras_object' from partially initialized module 'keras.saving.legacy.serialization' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/saving/legacy/serialization.py

Colab link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2DTH61Z4NPTPonxojGdsw1xBuZoySZr/view?usp=sharing

I need help to solve this problem and the model run successfully.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which tensorflow version are you using? It seems there is version mismatch issue .